# The type or namespace name 'Input' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine.Experimental'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using unity's new input system and getting this error, I tried a lot to fix it but can't find the problem. Please help me.

Error:

```
Assets\Player01.cs(4,32): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Input' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine.Experimental' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Full Script(C#):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Experimental.Input;

public class Player01 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputMaster controls;

    void Awake ()
    {
        controls.Player01.Shoot.performed += _ => Shoot();
    }

    void Shoot ()
    {
        Debug.Log("We shot the sherif!");
    }
    
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        controls.Enable();
    }
    private void OnDisable()
    {
        controls.Disable();
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there is no namespace of `UnityEngine.Experimental.Input`. But, it only says “'Input' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine.Experimental'”. ‘Experimental’ does exist and ‘Input’ does not. However, ‘InputSystem’ does. And that is the one you are looking for, not ‘Input’. You should change the first line to this:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Experimental.InputSystem;

public class Player01 : MonoBehaviour
...
```

Comment: Thank You, I found that I was implementing old method when Input System was experimental. Again Thank You very much

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, if the first solution did not work, Close vs studio / code if open, then go to Edit -> Project Settings -> Input System Manager. There will be only one option available. Click the button, save your scene. Open a script. This worked for me. A lot of tutorials do not mention this part.